# How much conservative ZF+AC and ZF+DC are over ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A logical theory $T_2$ is a (proof theoretic) conservative extension of a theory $T_1$ if the language of $T_2$ extends the language of $T_1$; every theorem of $T_1$ is a theorem of $T_2$; and any theorem of $T_2$ that is in the language of $T_1$ is already a theorem of $T_1$.

More generally, if $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas in the common language of $T_1$ and $T_2$, then $T_2$ is $\Gamma$-conservative over $T_1$ if every formula from $\Gamma$ provable in $T_2$ is also provable in $T_1$.

> **Question 1:** How much conservative ZF+AC and ZF+DC are over ZF? In the other words, what are the largest known sets of formulas $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$ in the language of set theory such that
>
> $\forall \varphi\in\Gamma_1~~~~~ZF+DC\vdash \varphi \Longleftrightarrow ZF\vdash \varphi$
>
> $\forall \varphi\in\Gamma_2~~~~~ZF+AC\vdash \varphi \Longleftrightarrow ZF\vdash \varphi$
>
> **Question 2:** It follows from [Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness) that restricted to the statements about natural numbers ZF+AC is $\Pi_{3}^1$ conservative over ZF. What can we say about $ZF+DC$ over $ZF$?

Comment: You are confusing something, the $\Pi^1_3$ refers to statements about integers, not sets. Adding any bit of choice is no longer conservative. If you mean that in the context of second-order arithmetic, then you should clarify that.

Comment: (My point being that statements about integers are not "the language of set theory", rather statement about sets are. And choice, of any kind, adds new provable statements about sets.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you please add edits if you think the question needs more clarification?

Comment: Ali, I can't edit, since I'm not sure what you are really trying to find out. I just remarked on what's unclear to me in the current formulation of the question, and why I am not sure what sort of answer you are expecting for. Shoenfield's theorem is true in $\sf ZF$, in particular in $\sf ZF+DC$ and $\sf ZFC$. But it's a theorem about statements about numbers, not about sets. So "conservativity" as you present it is the wrong term here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think what Ali probably wants to know is the largest class of sentences on ZF language such that $ZF+DC \vdash \psi \leftrightarrow ZF \vdash \psi$ for all $\psi$ in that class

Comment: @JonasGomes Yes, that is it.

Comment: @Jonas: But $\Pi^1_3$ refers to statement about **natural numbers**! That's not even the language of set theory! If conservative extensions refer to the original language of the theory, then the Levy absoluteness theorem should be referred to, not Shoenfield's.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for your useful comment. I edited the question.

Comment: You are right of course @AsafKaragila. I'll leave my comment to clarify this point for others.

Comment: Ali, to the edited question I don't think there is a neat answer. I have [written a note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3048) about absoluteness between $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZFC$, but the structure is based on reducing to $L[A]$ for suitable $A$'s, so you get $\sf ZFC$ rather than just $\sf ZF+DC$. The theorem that $\Delta_1$ are absolute between $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZFC$ extends to say that $\Pi_1$ are absolute between $\sf ZF+DC$ and $\sf ZFC$, but not quite about $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZF+DC$. I think that $\sf DC$ itself is a $\Pi_2$ statement (or maybe even $\Delta_2$) which would be a limited example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a very neat answer. In the case of $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZFC$, you have the Levy absoluteness theorem which tells us that $\Delta_1$ statements are absolute between $V$ and $L$. I extended this in [this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3048) by introducing a new notion of "bounded quantifiers", and showing that the class of absolute statements is strictly larger than just that (it's not new, I just tried to give it some structure).

In the case of $\sf ZF+DC$ things are a bit different. We can probably push the conservativity of $\sf ZFC$ over $\sf ZF+DC$ a bit more in the same way the Levy absoluteness can be extended to $\Pi_1$ statements in that case (by using countable elementary submodels and the Shoenfield absoluteness theorem). I expect that such example can be used to give a statement which is not absolute between $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZF+DC$ and has a relatively minimal complexity.

Comment: I've upgraded my comment to an answer; I'll add something about the second question later.